# How do I disable a button after 3 tries with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How would you disable the submit button after 3 tries?
This is all the code (GOT some help with javascript thanks to [DCR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4398966/dcr))

```js
/*This Script allows people to enter by using a form that asks for a
UserID and Password*/
function pasuser(form) {
if (form.identifier.value=="GG") { 
if (form.pass.value=="123") { 
  window.location('https://www.google.com/');
} else {
alert("Invalid Password");
}

} else {  alert("Invalid UserID");
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <script src="/server.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" name="identifier" required="">
        <label>Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="password" name="pass" required="">
        <label>Password</label>
      </div>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="pasuser(form)">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a variable and count up. In reality you'd do this server-side though, just like the login check, so this is kind of a moot exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do it is to add a counter and hide/remove the button if the counter reaches 3 and the credentials are still wrong.

**However, it is far more secure to do this on the server-side!!!**

The following is a JavaScript client-side solution based on your code, but again, checking only on client-side is not secure.

```js
/*This Script allows people to enter by using a form that asks for a
UserID and Password*/
var button = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
var attempts = 0;
function pasuser(form) {
  attempts++;
    if (form.identifier.value=="GG") { 
      if (form.pass.value=="123") { 
        attempts = 0;
        window.location('https://www.google.com/');
      } else {
        alert("Invalid Password");
        button.style.display = attempts === 3 ? "none" : "block";
      }

    } else {  alert("Invalid UserID");
      button.style.display = attempts === 3 ? "none" : "block";
    }
  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <script src="/server.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" name="identifier" required="">
        <label>Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="password" name="pass" required="">
        <label>Password</label>
      </div>
      <input id="submitBtn" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="pasuser(form)">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since he asks on how to disable the button, I would go with `button.disabled = attempts >= 3;` instead of hiding/displaying. This doesn't really matter though as most of that code should really be handled on the server anyway as you said

Comment: I tried server side and php but it isn't working don't know why. But, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Ethical38 If you want, try asking another question about your PHP attempt that did not work. Maybe someone could help you solve it!

Comment: Also, on line 9 of your code window.location doesn't work it should be window.location.assign

Comment: @Ethical38 I just used your code *as is* and added to it a few lines...

Comment: This is your mistake, not mine, I am sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
var trieds = 0;
function pasuser(form) {
    if (form.identifier.value=="GG") {
        if (form.pass.value=="123") {
            window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
        } else {
            alert("Invalid Password");
            trieds += 1;
        }
    } else {  
        alert("Invalid UserID");
        trieds += 1;
    }
    //Change <input type='button'> for <button>
    document.querySelector("button").disabled = (trieds === 3) ? true : false;
}
```